# Magento 2 contact us page tracking pixel

Tags: magento-2.1, contact-us, conversion

I want to track the leads from my contact us page.

I want to use google adwords tracking code for that job.

I know that under Stores->Configuration->Sales->Google API I can set the Google Adwords, but it's only for the checkout success page.

So how can I track the leads from the contact us form also?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to use Google Adwords tracking code, I'll assume you mean Google Analytics generally.

You can track page loads to the contact page with a specific goal set in Analytics specifying the page URL. In order to capture successful form submissions you will either need to redirect users to a success / thank you page and track that page loading as a goal.

Better yet, you can set up Google Tag Manager with an event for form submission success and you don't need a thank you page. Neither of these solutions is internal to Magento 2 other than the basic tracking setup you probably want in place regardless of the specific tracking request.

Comment: No, I talked about google adwords. About conversion code for successful contacts submit.

Comment: Then I would do it all with GTM, nothing else is going to give you the flexibility and detail without needing to constantly update code on the site.  
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6105160?hl=en